# How to remove "display: none" from my html and body tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

i have just entered my website and all of the contect doesnt seems to appear, in the source there is an inline css style display:none in the html tag and the body tag... is there a way to track what does give this css property to the body and html tag, so i could remove it.. I tried Firebug plugin for Mozilla Firefox, but i cant find anything... The website is running on Wordpress
here is the link http://p315468.for-test-only.ru/

Comment: Please add enough code to the question to reproduce the issue and remove the link. Because when the link gets removed there is no further usability for future users. See the help page https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

elements hidden with JQuery in (index):

```
$('html, body').hide()
```

just remark this line.

Comment: I found it, but i do not know where to delete it.. I haven't written this code

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.classname').css('display','block');
});
```

or using Id

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#ElementId').css('display','block');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to track down what JavaScript is causing that issue and you are using Wordpress, the first thing you can turn to is deactivate all the plugins and reactivate it one after another to see which plugin is causing that issue.

Comment: It was because of the jQuery updater plugin, but still i need the latest version of jQuery... it is 1 step foreword thanks to you

Comment: Did you managed to get the answer from your question? If yes can you mark the right answer, if not please let us know what other helps you need.

Comment: I have found the problematic jQuary in the inline (index), i am still looking for a way to remove it, i do not want to remove the plugin. the code is on 2404 line "$('html, body').hide()"

Comment: what version of jquery is that?

Comment: Latest stable version, that the plugin "jQuary updater" provides me whit "jquery-2.2.0.min.js"

Comment: the juery is minified I can't navigate to 2404 line. I don't think jquery will run hide function by itself though......

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but the code is inline, not in the "jquery-2.2.0.min.js" i just provided you the version of the jquary. I think i am jus going to use "$('html, body').show()" it seems to be working fine

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#Element').css('display','');
$('#Element').css('display','block');
```

Answer (score 0):

give a class to it and in jquery do

```
$( window ).load(function() {
  $(".classname").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you write inline css in your home page,
so you need to remove dispaly:none; from your html and body tag from your home page

and it's working perfect.

Comment: I understand that it is because of the display:none; but it seems there is JavaScript or jQuary that is adding this style, i am look for a way to track the script and deleting the command

Comment: You can remove them by adding this line in your jQuery: `$("#ls-global").css({ 'display' : ''});`